# Iterating over BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am iterating over table that I parsed from html page. I want to iterate over BeautifulSoup object and parse the texts between tag and store them into a list. However, the code below keeps giving me only the very last text from the iteration. How do I add on texts in this problem?

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table",attrs={"id":"mvp_NBA"}).find("tbody").findAll("tr")

for row in table:
    key = []
    season = row.find_all("th")
    for year in season:
        y = year.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        key.append(y)
print key
```

Comment: please provide html/link Or what is your output ? and what is your desired output ?

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html I am trying to loop over the table of mvp players and parse years as a key and player name as a value

Comment: here you are getting years only as a key and as per your question and code that you want all the years but getting only last one so to to that i have modified your code check answer. And to get players you can modified it yourself then make ka dictionary of it to get key as years and name as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table",attrs={"id":"mvp_NBA"}).find("tbody").findAll("tr")

key = []
for row in table:
    season = row.findAll("th", {'class': 'left'})
    for year in season:
        y = year.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        key.append(y)
print key
```

The only mistake you are doing that in your for loop on every ilteration you empyted your list `key=[]` i have modified your code little bit and it is giving your desired output.